# How to change root in RefineryCMS to blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, refinerycms

In my `config/routes.rb` I have the following

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do

  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  root :to => 'refinery/blog/posts#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

end
```

I ran `rake routes` in the terminal. Then committed and pushed. Then ran `heroku run rake routes` but when I load the app, it still loads loads the home page as the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your route before Refinery's mount point because Refinery has a wildcard route so that it can handle 404s and basically be the backstop for your application.  So, in general, mount Refinery after every other route.

Comment: Ok thank you, that worked. But that needs to be repeated after all custom routes? is there a sample of a `routes.rb` that we can browse?

Comment: And was the rest of the process fine, or are there steps that can be eliminated?